# Usar el modulo xlrd de python

Tags: python, xlrd

Instalé el módulo xlrd en mi computadora y no puedo utilizarlo. Al importar xlrd me aparece lo siguiente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    import xlrd
  File "C:\Python27\xlrd.py", line 1, in <module>
    from xlrd import open_workbook
ImportError: cannot import name open_workbook
```

¿alguien sabe a qué se debe esto y cómo lo corrijo?

Comment: ¿Cómo has instalado el paquete? Es necesario más contexto para poder reproducir tu error. Acabo de instalar la versión 1.0.0 usando `pip` y `conda` y ninguno me ha dado problemas.

Comment: ¿Qué está haciendo `xlrd.py` en el `PYTHON_HOME`? ¿Has llamando a tu script igual que el módulo?